# Query 2 fields in mysql table

Tags: mysql

This is probably very basic, but any examples I have tried have failed.
I need to query a single MySQL table
If "field 1" is not null & "field 2" = No, return some warning.

It should query every row in the table and give a warning

Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Use the `IF` function of mysql.

Comment: Post some sample data and desired result will be more help.

Comment: Additionally, show what you have attempted. SO is not here to solve a problem, but to troubleshoot issues you have.

Comment: why should it return a warning? Why not just return the ids of the rows that meet this criteria and then issue a warning in your app if needed?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 = 'NO';

hope it helps :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question